# How to define a list of recursive calls to a function in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, iteration, higher-order-functions

What I would like to do is define a function like this:

```
[f 0, f f 0, f f f 0, f f f f 0, f f f f f 0..]
```

Or in other words, where each element is the last element that is run through a function.

I have tried a few times to get this working with ways similar to ways I have seen the Fibonacci sequence in Haskell, by calling the list with the first few elements pre-defined:

```
fib = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)

ls = 0 : f 0 : f (last ls)
```

If I define f as a simple addOne function like so:

f = (+ 1)

I get this error:

```
<interactive>:124:5: error:
* Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
  Expected type: [[a]]
    Actual type: [a]
* In the expression: 0 : (f 0) : f (last y)
  In an equation for `y': y = 0 : (f 0) : f (last y)
* Relevant bindings include
    y :: [[a]] (bound at <interactive>:124:1)
```

How do I create a list that functions like this does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to define this yourself, vs use iterate as pointed out by @WillemVanOnsem, then simple primitive recursion is your friend:

```
f :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
f g x = let new = g x in new `seq` new : f g new
```

This is similar to iterate except that iterate starts with the element you provide (the first `x`) instead of the first application of the function:

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f x =  x : iterate f (f x)
```

A self-education can be acquired by [hoogling](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3A%3A+%28a+-%3E+a%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D&scope=set%3Astackage) for functions of this type and reading the [implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#iterate) of any search hits found in the base package.

Answer (score 6):

I like your attempt

```
ls = 0 : f 0 : f (last ls)
```

These are the problems with it:

- No type signature. Always write type signatures. They are technically speaking optional, but boy do they help to understand what's going on and what you even want.
- You're trying to apply `f` directly to a list, but it's supposed to operate on *list elements*. (That's the cause of your error message.)
- `last` on an infinite list can be no good. Anyways this is not what you want: `f` should be applied to *all* elements of the tail instead. That's what `map` is there for.

So, a correct and complete implementation of that attempt is the following:

```
iterate' :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
 -- altn.:  (Int->Int) -> [Int], without x₀ but always starting from 0
iterate' f x₀ = ls
 where ls = x₀ : f x₀ : map f (tail ls)
```

N.B. this doesn't actually give `[f 0, f (f 0), f (f (f 0)) ..]` but starts from `0`. To start from `f 0`, simply remove the standalone `x₀`:

```
iterate' f x₀ = ls
 where ls = f x₀ : map f (tail ls)
```

...which doesn't terminate however (thanks @WillNess), because the `tail` would now recurse forever. *But you don't actually need `tail`*! This is the proper definition:

```
iterate' f x₀ = ls
 where ls = f x₀ : map f ls
```

Answer (score 4):

Or roll your own:

```
fn f a = (f a) : (fn f (f a))

main = print $ take 6 $ fn (5+) 1
```

Output:

```
[6,11,16,21,26,31]
```

Answer (score 3):

Haskell has already a function for that: [**`iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate). For example:

```
Prelude> take 10 (iterate (2*) 1)
[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]
```

Your question is slightly different since the first element should be `f 0`, instead of `0`, but we can simply apply `f` to it, or use `tail :: [a] -> [a]` on the result. For example:

```
ls :: Num a => (a -> a) -> [a]
ls = tail . flip iterate 0
```

For example:

```
Prelude> take 10 (ls (1+))
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```